# How do I make sense of this Java syntax, a class name in parentheses before a method name?

Tags: java, syntax

I'm seeing this syntax and can't understand what it means. It doesn't look like a regular object instantiation. The 'new' keyword isn't there and the class name is put in parenthesis... then there's a method call at the end.

`MyClass myObj = (MyClass) someMethod(arg);`

Comment: the word you are looking for is "cast"

Answer (score 2):

In Java,

```
someMethod(arg)
```

is a *call of a method* named `someMethod` with a single parameter `arg`.

All methods (except `void` ones) return a value. The type of the return value is part of method definition. In your case, we don't know what the `someMethod` returns (because you didn't provide its definition), but we can assume it is not `void`.

The expression

```
(MyClass) obj
```

is a *type cast*, which tells the compiler to treat `obj` as if it was of type `MyClass`. During compilation, compiler checks that the definition of `obj` is compatible with `MyClass`, and if it is, it allows you to treat it like one. During run time, Java virtual machine checks that the actual object `obj` is actually instance of class `MyClass`. If it is not, it will throw a `ClassCastException`.

Typically, type casts are used to "upgrade" how the compiler sees an object into something more specific. For example, if a pet shop by definition sells `Animal`s, and you ordered a `Hamster`, then you can reasonably assume thet what you get is not just an `Animal`, but a `Hamster` (assuming `Hamster extends Animal`).

Now, put this together and you get a type cast applied to a method return value.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method somewhere that is returning an object based on the `arg` arugment.  The developer has provided a cast, to coerce the object into the `MyClass` type.

This is common in a Singleton pattern (where the same object instance is returned if the `arg` argument is the same), or in a static constructor.  Usually the method is doing a `new MySubclass( ... )` somewhere and returning that.